# Random Message v14

Tags: discord, discord.js

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkFuU.jpg)

I want my Discord bot to send the following text message to one of the random text channels on the servers it is on, it doesn't give an error but it doesn't work, I'm new to this,So I don't know much about v14 can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random channel from a guild by using `<Collection>.random` method like this:

```js
interaction.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.isTextBased() && channel.sendable)?.random().send("Hello!")
```

`filter` method is used for only getting text based and sendable channels

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has some problems. Here's the problems I found in it:

1. **Syntax Errors**: There are some syntax errors, such as a missing opening parenthesis `'('` in the `client.on` method.
2. **Incorrect Logic**: You are not fetching a random text channel correctly from the guild channels collection. Also, `ChannelType.GuildText` would give you the string value for checking the channel type, but you are not using it to filter out text channels.
3. **Permission Issues**: Before sending a message to a channel, you should check if the bot has permission to send messages in that channel.

Now, I revised your code, and it's here:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
    ]
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    // Fetch all text channels from the guild
    const textChannels = guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type === 'GUILD_TEXT');

    // Select a random text channel from the list of text channels
    const randomChannel = textChannels.random();

    // Check if the bot has permissions to send messages in the channel
    if (randomChannel && randomChannel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES')) {
        randomChannel.send("hi");
    }
});

client.login('YOUR_TOKEN');
```

I used the `random()` method on the filtered channels collection to get a random text channel.

Also, if you have a problem again, check if the bot has the necessary permissions.

And also, replace `'YOUR_TOKEN'` with your bot's token.

The `guildCreate` event triggers when the bot joins a new server, so this will send "hi" to a random text channel only on servers the bot just joined. If you want to do this on existing servers, you'd need a different approach.

Comment: yes, that's what I want, I want my discord bot to send a message every 1 hour to random text channels on the servers it is in.

Comment: Then, you'll need to set up an interval and iterate over all the guilds the bot is in. This approach might also be seen as spammy.